# Is it possible to use standard C++ threads instead of FLTK timeouts to update window?

Tags: c++, fltk

I need to create a simple animation that does itself without user interaction.
There is [a bunch of solutions](http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/) that uses included FLTK timers to redraw the window in fixed time periods and that scheme is working fine without me moving the mouse or pressing keys, but as soon as it's changed to simple loop with redraw() in std::thread, everything breaks and redraw only works when events are being pushed to program by user.

Here's my code. If you bother launching it, you will see that `updateFunc` spams into the output each second steadily, but `draw` only appears there when you do something with mouse or keyboard and therefore the window changes its color. If that's normal behaviour, I need to change it somehow.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#include <FL/Fl.h>
#include <FL/gl.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Gl_Window.h>
chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> execStart;
void log(const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg,fmt);
    fprintf(stderr,"[%10.3f] ",chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(
        chrono::system_clock::now()-execStart
    ).count()/1000.0);
    vfprintf(stderr,fmt,arg);
    fprintf(stderr,"\n");
    va_end(arg);
}

double rand01() {return (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;}

class Window: public Fl_Gl_Window {
private:
    thread updateThread;
    void updateFunc() {
        while (1) {
            log("%s",__func__);
            this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
            redraw();
        }
    }
protected:
    void draw() {
        log("%s",__func__);
        glClearColor(rand01(),rand01(),rand01(),1);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
public:
    Window(int x,int y,int w,int h,const char* s):
        Fl_Gl_Window(x,y,w,h,s),
        updateThread(&Window::updateFunc,this)
        {}
    Window(): Window(320,240,800,600,"FLTK OpenGL test") {}
};

int main() {
    execStart=chrono::system_clock::now();
    log("execution started");
    srand(time(0));

    Window *wnd=new Window();
    wnd->show();

    return Fl::run();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s normal behavior. But luckily for you, FLTK have it covered.

In short, you must call `Fl::lock()` before starting your thread, and in your thread `Fl::lock()` before doing any updates, `Fl::unlock()` after updating the GUI, and `Fl::awake()` instead of `redraw`.

[Read the documentation](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/advanced.html#advanced_multithreading) for more info.

Comment: Nice, it werks!
Just to make sure, is it also possible to wait for FLTK to finish drawing from worker thread? because there's pretty much excess loop iterations in my thread which is not really good so I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: FLTK only have half of that. On the background thread, you can schedule a function on the render thread with `Fl::awake(Fl_Awake_Handler cb, void* userdata)` call, and wait for the completion. In that function call `redraw`, and notify the background thread that it’s done. You need to implement waiting+notifications yourself, the modern C++ way is probably `std::promise<void>`

Comment: Or if you’re going to post multiple requests, you can use std::queue for results, std::mutex to guard it, and std::condition_variable to implement sleep/wakeup.